# LinkManager.ResolveTargetSite is obsolete - what is the replacement

Tags: link-manager

In Sitecore 9.3, if I try and call `LinkManager.ResolveTargetSite`, I see an obsolete message:

```
Please use IItemBasedSiteResolver instead.
```

But I can find absolutely nothing about how to use IItemBasedSiteResolver. Where is it? What ddl? And how do I use it? Is there an example somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think its a typo in the obsolete message and they want you to use the `IItemSiteResolver` instead. If you follow the `LinkManager.ResolveTargetSite` code through, eventually it gets to this method:

```
[Obsolete("To be removed when ResolveTargetSite(Item) is removed.")]
private static IItemSiteResolver CreateSiteResolver()
{
  return (IItemSiteResolver) new OptionsDecoratedSiteResolver(new ItemUrlBuilderOptions(), ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService<IItemSiteResolver>());
}
```

You can see there, that internally, the `LinkManager` call is using `IItemSiteResolver`.

So if you inject `IItemSiteResolver` into your class/controller etc... then you can call the `ResolveSite(Item item)` method on it.